# SQL Server : rewriting WHERE clause based on data in million records table

Tags: sql, sql-server

See below query which is taking nearly 10 minutes to run. Can this be rewritten to fetch results faster, mainly the where clause condition...

Number of records:

- Table tmp_TimeIntervals: 1440
- Table tmp_Activities: 1299688

Code:

```
select
    i.ID,
    sl.SPID,
    i.PeriodStart,
    DATEDIFF(mi, i.PeriodStartUTC, sl.ENDTIME)
from
    tmp_TimeIntervals i 
join
    tmp_Activities sl on (sl.StartTime <= i.PeriodStartUTC
                          and (sl.Endtime > i.PeriodStartUTC 
                          and sl.Endtime < PeriodEndUTC))
```

Regards

Comment: How many matches are you expecting?  Are there overlaps or are you expecting just one match?  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: which indexes do you currently have? query plan would be good as well.

Comment: you want to find overlapping intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want overlapping intervals in `tmp_TimeIntervals` and `tmp_Activities` then the SQL query may look as follows:

```
select
    i.ID,
    sl.SPID,
    i.PeriodStart,
    DATEDIFF(mi, i.PeriodStartUTC, sl.ENDTIME)
from tmp_TimeIntervals i 
join tmp_Activities sl 
on sl.StartTime <= i.PeriodEndUTC and sl.Endtime > i.PeriodStartUTC
```

and for the efficient run you definitely need index `tmp_Activities(StartTime , Endtime, SPID)`. The `SPID` can be removed if it is a key of clustered index.

```
create index ix_tmp_Activities on tmp_Activities(StartTime , Endtime) include (SPID)
```

Another index `tmp_TimeIntervals(PeriodEndUTC, PeriodStartUTC, PeriodStart, ID)` can be helpful as well since SQL Server can use a merge join more easily. Again `ID` can be removed from the index if it is a key of clustered index.

```
create index ix_tmp_TimeIntervals on tmp_TimeIntervals(PeriodEndUTC, PeriodStartUTC) include (PeriodStart, ID)
```

Comment: @user3657339 what is the result time of the query processing using this approach? thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any framework then use built in method to get record in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things
Would be good to check estimated execution plan and check the costs whats chewing up.

Try and place a left outer join as it will create a subquery lookup which will be faster than your inner join.
As the concept is push down predicate.

Another colnsideration before creating index check column lengths. If data writes are not frequent consider generating a columnstore index will be 10x faster than what tou getting now.